# Instantiate a resolved promise in ES2015

Tags: javascript, promise

What is the canonical way to create a resolved promise in ES 2015?

Comment: That should work.  What behavior are you seeing?

Comment: Unable to delete, have re-worded my question. (original question was a mistake on my part)

Comment: I am using "empty" for the then part: 

    CallReturningPromise().then(empty);
    function empty(ignored)
     {
     } // empty

Comment: Error in Stack Overflow: no way to format code in a comment.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

The [`Promise.resolve`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve) class method returns a promise that is instantiated as resolved with a value you can specify:

```js
var promise = Promise.resolve(100);
```

Comment: In node, I get this warning: Warning: a promise was created in a handler but was not returned from it.

Comment: I'm guessing you're using bluebird as your promise implementation, right? Try updating to the latest version of the library, I think it was fixed in version 3.3.4: http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/changelog.html#3.3.4

Comment: @Himmators - couldn't reproduce using an older version of bluebird, so I'm not sure what is causing the warning for you. Which version of node, and what, if any, promise library are you using?

Comment: Does this mean that you can use ".resolve(0)" after a system call that returns a promise? Is this the same as syscall().then(function(){}) ?

Comment: Didn't work for me. I got error "TypeError: S(...).resolve is not a function" for sys function browser.notifications.create in a Webextension. I'll just use an empty function for "then" since I don't need to do anything after the async operation completes.