# JavaScript if/else statement, one has ajax, the other does not, but both should redirect to same place

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a standard form with fields. One of those fields is a file upload. The form is processed via ajax and in the success block, IF there are attached files, I need to make another ajax call to upload the file. This is where I'm struggling. If an upload needs to be done, I execute the if/ block, perform ajax, then on ajax success, redirect. In the /else block, I don't need to perform any ajax, so I can immediately redirect. I don't like having this redirect twice as it is not DRY. I know I can instead use a function in each of these places, then only have the redirect once, but that still seems to violate the DRY standard since I'm still calling the function twice.

Is there a better way to write this?

```
          if (files.length > 0) {

            readFile(files[0],function(filestring){
              var fileObj = new Object();
                  fileObj.file = filestring.split(";base64,")[1];
                  fileObj.fullFileName = document.getElementById("file").files[0].name;
                  fileObj.fileName = fileObj.fullFileName.split(".")[0];
                  fileObj.ext = fileObj.fullFileName.split(".")[1];
                  fileObj.leadid = resp.leadid;

                  doAjax(fileObj,endpoints.file).then(function(resp){
                    
                    window.location.href = "returnURL";
                  });

            });              
          }else{
              window.location.href = "returnURL";
          }
```

I cannot think of a better/cleaner way to write this and I am not sure how to search for this on Google, since I'm not sure what the correct terminology would be to describe this problem.

In case you need to see it, here is the doAjax function.

```
function doAjax(data,url){
  return  $.ajax({
            url: url,
            cache: false,
            method: "post",
            dataType:"json",
            data: data
        });
}
```

Here is the readFile function

```
function readFile(files,callback){
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsDataURL(files);
  reader.onload = function (e) {
    callback(reader.result);
  }
  reader.onerror = function (error) {
      console.log('Error: ', error);
  };  
}
```

Comment: Use `async/await` syntax and return early?

Comment: Thanks I will search that real quick and see if it might work

Comment: Maybe put the `if` statement inside the `doAjax(files, endpoints)` function without `else`, this way `.then` will run anyway.

Comment: Thanks @MaxS., but I only want to run the doAjax if there are files to upload. I mean, I suppose I could modify the doAjax statement to skip the ajax entirely though with a certain condition, so this could work. Or better yet, write a special function for this instead of doAjax, since that is my generic ajax function. Although, then I think my special function will still have this same problem...

Comment: I see, anyway, see the example I posted below.

Comment: I would image your `readFile` is also asynchronous, hence the call back - so returning the doAjax promise (or any `return` within `readFile` callback) would be too late).   Ensure readFile returns a promise and then return an empty/resolved promise (see [this answer](readFile) when 0 files.  Though I'm not sure about returning from the inner ajax OTOMH so would need to look into that.

Comment: Thanks @freedomn-m good idea. I'll need some time to put these ideas in action. To your point, and I think you and Max are on similar page here, no reason for the if/else if the readFile is empty.

Comment: I should have reviewed my comment: see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37729403/instantiate-a-resolved-promise-in-es2015

Comment: @freedomn-m thanks, this could be it or the async/await thing mentioned above. when I posted this, I forgot about the async readFile function, and now I have to deal  with that also. This'll take some time to unpack, but I'll post back here when I have something.

Comment: After playing with async/await for a while, I realized the fix is worse than the problem. I will live with it @MaxS. answer would have been a good fix if I were willing to use axios or rework my code (which I'm not). Thanks for all your suggestions! This was helpful https://simon-schraeder.de/posts/filereader-async/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
doAjax = function(files, endpoints) {
    if (files.length > 0) {
      readFile(files[0], function(filestring) {
          var fileObj = new Object();
          fileObj.file = filestring.split(";base64,")[1];
          fileObj.fullFileName = document.getElementById("file").files[0].name;
          fileObj.fileName = fileObj.fullFileName.split(".")[0];
          fileObj.ext = fileObj.fullFileName.split(".")[1];
          fileObj.leadid = resp.leadid;

          return resp;
      });
    }

     return [];
}

doAjax(files, endpoints).then(function(resp) {
    window.location.href = "returnURL";
});
```

EDIT:
I was reading your post again, уоu say `The form is processed via ajax and in the success block, IF there are attached files, I need to make another ajax call to upload the file` The question is, where do you perform validation? Validation has to be done along with the form on the server side. A hacker may be able to upload files without the having `success` back from the server. This is best done using one call, уоu send the attached files (if they exist), validate the form, if success then уоu store the files, if not then уоu throw an error, then redirect the user when уоu get the response whether they attached files or not.

Using Axios this would look something like this:

```
let form_data = new FormData();
form_data.append('data_to_validate', data);

if (files.length > 0) {
    form_data.append('attachment', myFiles.files[0]);
}

axios({
    url: '/api',
    method: 'post',
    data: form_data,
    headers: {'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'}
})
.then(response => {
    window.location.href = response.returnURL;
})
.catch(error => {
});
```

Comment: Hmm, this is indeed pretty clean, thanks!

Comment: Is it possible to provide some code to see this "in action"?  I can't see  how `return []` would allow you to call `.then()` - so I must be missing some vital bit of info.

Comment: Actually that is a good point @freedomn-m I may have to try this before marking correct as it doesn't actually have the ajax

Comment: @garek007 See the comment I added to the answer.